# Keeping a constant window size with WM WINDOWS in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Morning all,

I have a tcl/tk application and for the windows size I have the following code:

```
wm title . "Relay Switch Application"
wm attributes . -alpha "1" 
wm geometry . 1600x500+100+100
```

Within the window, there is 3 labelframes positioned at:

> x1: 10
>   x2: 200 
>   x3: 320

On my PC, each labelframe are side by side with about 20 pixel gaps between them.
On my work laptop, the second labelframe is over lapping the first.

How do I change or add to my code so the windows contents are postioned correctly for whatever screen resolution?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: You basically _can't_ get what you've asked for. You'll have to make do with what you can actually get…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fact of GUIs that absolute positioning of windows (either within a main window with `place` or of the top level with `wm geometry`) is usually a bad idea. This is because of little things like screen pixel densities varying or font widths changing and so on, but it's just something that you have to put up with. Instead, you should write your application to use Tk's other geometry managers, as those adapt to the size of the content and the amount of overall screen space that the OS and user conspire to give you.

For example, here's how to put three labelframes side-by-side with `pack`:

```
# Make some labelframes
labelframe .x1 -text "This is X1"
labelframe .x2 -text "This is X2"
labelframe .x3 -text "This is X3"

# Lay them out
pack .x1 .x2 .x3 -side left -fill both -expand yes
# You might want to experiment with the -padx and -pady options
```

If you need complex placement rules, such as stacking in several directions or making one window a size that is a multiple of the size of another, you'll probably use `grid`, which is a geometry manager that is sophisticated enough to handle almost all layouts you can conceive of in normal GUIs. It'd be fairly simple for this case:

```
# Put the labelframes in the grid…
grid .x1 .x2 .x3 -sticky nsew

# … and define how the system expands
grid columnconfigure {0 1 2} -weight 1
grid rowconfigure 0 -weight 1
```

Comment: If you know neither pack nor grid, I would advise to start learning grid first. It is easier to understand and more powerful than pack. With grid you can create any layout you can with pack. The reverse is not always true. (But if things can be done with pack, it normally requires less typing.)